# React/Redux: how to hold login fail

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I'm very beginner in React/Redux and I was trying to do something in an already existing code, just to understand how it works. The part I want to edit is the connection part. As it's now, if the login and password are OK, you go to a new page, and if not, it does nothing.

The only simple thing I'm trying to do is to show the user their login informations are wrong, by adding a red border on the fields for example.

So here is the code I added, I'll try not to show you useless code and not to forget useful code, but let me know if you need more.

The first thing I did is adding a constant for the error in **actionTypes.js**:

```
export const AUTH_REQUEST = 'AUTH_REQUEST';
export const AUTH_RECEIVE = 'AUTH_RECEIVE';
export const AUTH_ERROR = 'AUTH_ERROR';
```

Then in **actions/auth.js**, I added the *authError* function and called it after a fail response from the server:

```
function authRequest() {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.AUTH_REQUEST
  };
}

function authReceive(authToken) {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.AUTH_RECEIVE,
    authToken
  };
}

function authError() {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.AUTH_ERROR
  };
}

export function fetchLogin(email, password) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(authRequest());

    const urlApi = `//${AUTH_BACKEND_HOST}:${AUTH_BACKEND_PORT}/${AUTH_BACKEND_URL.login}`
    fetch(urlApi, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email,
        password
      })
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if(response.ok) {
        // SUCCESS
        response.json().then(function(json) {
          dispatch(authReceive(json.key));
          dispatch(push('/'));
        });
      } else {
        // FAIL
        response.json().then(function(json) {
          dispatch(authError());
        });
      }
    })
    .catch(function(ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    });
  };
}
```

Now, in **reducers/auth.js**:

```
const initialState = {
  authToken: '',
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
  errorMessage: ''
}

export default function (state=initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionType.AUTH_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
      };
    case actionType.AUTH_RECEIVE:
      return authLogin(state, action);
    case actionType.AUTH_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: true,
        errorMessage: 'Incorrect login or password!'
      };
  }
  return state;
}

function authLogin(state, action) {
  const { authToken } = action;
  return {
    ...state,
    isFetching: false,
    authToken
  };
}
```

Until now, it seems to work when I inspect it in Firefox. The state contains  the *error* and *errorMessage* values.

So here is my **components/Login/presenter.jsx** which I thought was going to display the right HTML depending on the state:

```
import React from 'react';

const Login = React.createClass({

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const email = this.refs.email.value
    const password = this.refs.password.value

    this.props.onAuth(email, password);
  },

  render() {
    const { errorMessage } = this.props

      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Email <input ref="email" placeholder="email" required /></label>
          <label>Password <input ref="password" placeholder="password" type="password" required /></label><br />
          <p>{errorMessage}</p>
          <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </form>
      )    
  }    
});

export default Login;
```

And here is **components/Login/index.js** which I think imports the presenter and do... things...:

```
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import Login from './presenter';

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onAuth: bindActionCreators(actions.fetchLogin, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (Login);
```

---

Edit : it seems that one of the problems is that I'm not mapping the state to props. I tried Mael Razavet and azium's answers, adding mapStateToProps in Login/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import Login from './presenter';

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onAuth: bindActionCreators(actions.fetchLogin, dispatch)
  };
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {
    errorMessage: state.errorMessage
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (Login);
```

But it seems that errorMessage is still undefined.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you passing the `errorMessage` prop from?

Comment: It seems that it could be the problem, as Mael Razavet pointed out. Even if I don't even know what it means. I think I don't understand the worflow in a React/Redux app :|

Comment: That is how your get the changes (and more generally the information) from your store onto your components for use. It is basically taking your store which you are updating with your reducers and mapping that information onto props so it can be used by your components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to map your state to props. In your case, you should add this content to your **components/Login/index.js**:

```
import * as actions from './actions/auth.js';
import Login from './presenter';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    error: state.login.error,
    errorMessage: state.login.errorMessage,
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onAuth: (email, password) => {
      dispatch(actions.fetchLogin(email, password));      
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login); // maps your state to your component's props
```

In your **reducers/auth.js**:

```
const initialState = {
  authToken: '',
  isFetching: false,
  error: false,
  errorMessage: ''
}

export default function loginReducer(state=initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionType.AUTH_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        isFetching: true
    };
    case actionType.AUTH_RECEIVE:
      return authLogin(state, action);
    case actionType.AUTH_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: true,
        errorMessage: 'Incorrect login or password!'
      };
  }
  return state;
}

function authLogin(state, action) {
  const { authToken } = action;
  return {
    ...state,
    isFetching: false,
    authToken
  };
}
```

Then, in your code, you should be combining your reducer like:

```
import { combineReducers, createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Login from './components/Login';
import login from './reducers/auth.js'; //import your default reducer function

//COMBINE REDUCERS
const reducers = combineReducers({
  //reducers go here 
  login, //name of your reducer => this is is why your access your state like state.login
});

//WRAP WITH STORE AND RENDER
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Login/>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));
```

In Redux, you manage your state (setState) in a different layer (reducer) than your actual component. To do so, you need to map your state from the reducer to the component so you can use it as a props. This is why in your Login class, you are able to do :

```
const { errorMessage } = this.props; // now you can use errorMessage directly or this.props.errorMessage
```

This errorMessage comes from your state managed in your reducer and can be used in your component as **this.props.errorMessage**.

Here is the link to the tutorial which helped me understand Redux in React : https://github.com/happypoulp/redux-tutorial
It should help you understand better the workflow

Comment: So you mean when you get the state, you need to map it to props so you can use the props? But where should I write this? In a **Login/index.jsx** file I have a *mapDispatchToProps* function which I suppose binds an action, and I have a *export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps) (Login);*, which honnestly I don't even know what is, but I suppose I can't have 2 *export default connect* in the same jsx.

Comment: you're very close, just replace `null` with `mapStateToProps`. connect takes two arguments the first is the one in this answer

Comment: Sorry, I forgot something in my post: **presenter.jsx** is with **index.jsx** in a **Login** folder, and I think **index.jsx** imports **presenter.jsx**, so azium's answer may be right. Plus I made some mistakes, there are no **actions.js** or **reducers.js** files, but **actions** and **reducers** are folders with **index.js** and other stuffs inside. Could you check my edit and tell me? Because I tried both your answers and still can't make it work.

Comment: @azium Thank you, I edited my post to include the part about /Login/index.js. I tried your answer but errorMessage is still undefined. I'm probably doing this totally wrong.

Comment: I edited my answer to add the mapping between your actions and you dispatch. Tell me if it is working ?

Comment: It's not working for now but still thank you mate, but I don't get why you import { login } since the default function reducer doesn't have a name? And so how to import it without a name? Plus, why would it be *state.login.error* and *state.login.errorMessage* since I didn't write something about *.login* in the reducer?

Comment: Have a look at this codepen.io, it should help : http://codepen.io/joschka/pen/VaWPRq

Comment: Thanks for that last edit, indeed the reducers where combined in another file I didn't show in my post, with "auth" instead of "login". Now the message appears! Thank you mate, now I'm going to try to understand everything from the beginning. Many thanks.

Comment: Good news !! Don't forget to assign it as resolved please :)